# Technique or Tool for uniform mesh spacing?

Tags: modeling

So I have a nice circular array of identical parts (64 in total) on an engine I am building. 
I need to push them all out a very small amount from the their center of origin.

Is there a tool or a technique that someone knows, or another post that might help me with this.

I need each to be spaced identically along their normals.

UPDATE:
Thanks to JackDaw, I have formulated a complete Answer for those wishing to do this in the future:

Figured it out. The Icon for only Origins, is called Manipulate Center points in 2.79b. 
For people wanting to do this in the future, building on what Jackdaw said:
1. Make sure each object has it pivot where you want it to move from. 
2. Make sure the cursor is in the center of the location you want to scale out from.
3. Turn on the Manipulate Center Points (Shortcut Alt+Comma)
4. Select your pivot point (located next to shading method on the bottom toolbar) use median point or 3d cursor.
5. Press S and it will move the objects from that point.

Thank you Jack Daw.

I even made a demo video because this is great to know. Thanks again.
https://youtu.be/RTndO8tfUIw

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more details about how your objects/parts are organized in the scene... If they still are in the array it should be possible to just adjust your mesh/object/empty so that they move out.

That said... Blender is not a CAD tool so you cannot expect that level of precision.

Comment: Not in an array, just an array (many similar objects, equally spaced in a uniform fashion)

Imagine for a second if you will:
Each part is its own mesh. 
Each part needs to be distanced from the center point of origin. 

Like 64 equally spaced satillites around the earth, they all need to be pushed out one kilometer in their respective directions.

Comment: Or simpler, if I have 4 cubes, Cube 1 at 5,0, cube 2 at 0,5 cube 3 at 0,-5 and cube 4 at -5,0. If I want to make them all moved further away from 0,0 by 1, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are located on the same distance from the centre you should be able to use scale from 3D Cursor (placed at centre) with Only Origins set. If you need to an exact distance that will need to be calculated.

[image]

Or in Blender 2.79b
[image]

Comment: The Problem is, I dont want to deform them in anyway. I just want to move them.

Comment: If you set Only Origins you should not get any scaling on the objects

Comment: How do I do this using blender 2.79? I am not using 2.8 until it isnt in beta.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Jack. You rock!